# Rllvm and compiler packages: R compilation

Tags: r

This is a fairly general question about the future of R: Any hope to see a merger of `compiler`and `Rllvm` (from Omegahat) or another JIT compilation scheme for R (I know there is Ra, but not updated recently)?

In my tests the speed gain from `compiler` are marginal for "complicated" functions...

Comment: This sounds more like a question for the r development mailing list. Based on my general impressions I would say "probably not".  Are your complicated functions already based on heavily vectorized (and hence efficient) functions?  I think a more promising direction for not-so-easily-automatically-optimized situations is the increased simplicity of embedding C++ etc. (i.e. Rcpp), inline if necessary ...

Comment: Ben, make that an answer rather than a comment so that I can upvote...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What matters isn't how complicated a function is but what kinds of computations it performs.  The compiler will make most difference for functions dominated by interpreter overhead, such as ones that perform mostly simple operations on scalar or other small data.  In cases like that I have seen a factor of 3 for artificial examples and a a bit
better than a factor of 2 for some production code. Functions that spend most of their time in operations implemented in native code, like linear algebra operations, will see little benefit.

This is just the first release of the compiler and it will evolve over time.  LLVM is one of several possible direction we will look at but probably not for a while.  In any case, I would expect using something like LLVM to provide further improvements in cases where the current compiler already makes a difference, but not to add much in cases where it does not.

Answer (score 4):

(Moving from a comment to an answer ...)

This sounds more like a question for the r development mailing list. Based on my general impressions I would say "probably not". Are your complicated functions already based on heavily vectorized (and hence efficient) functions? I think a more promising direction for not-so-easily-automatically-optimized situations is the increased simplicity of embedding C++ etc. (i.e. Rcpp), inline if necessary